# PhoneGap - onProgress - Target null?

Tags: javascript, eclipse, dom, cordova

I am using PhoneGap (Cordova) file transfer and the onProgress function to show the user the progress of the download.

So far it is working very well, however I am trying to have several downloads progressing at the same time and I need to have a valid "target" property within the onProgress event, but it always reads as null.

Why is that? Is there any way for it to show the target, as in the name of the file it is providing information about?

```
var ft0 = new FileTransfer();
ft0.onprogress = onProgress;
ft0.download( url, filePath, onDownloadSuccess, onDownloadError );

function onProgress(progressEvent) {
....
```

Here is the property readout of the onProgress event

```
type: undefined; 
bubbles: false; 
cancelBubble: false; 
cancelable: false; 
lengthComputable: true; 
loaded: 5510; 
total: 56456; 
target: null;
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the progress event as defined by [W3C spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/progress-events/) does not have a target.

you could enclose the download operations in a closure and have access to the file name, something like this:

```
filePaths.each(function(filePath) {
   var ft = new FileTransfer();

   ft.onprogress = function(progressEvent) {
      //onProgress for filePath
   };

   button.addEventListener("click", function() {
      ft.abort();
   }, false);

   ft.download( url, filePath, onDownloadSuccess, onDownloadError );
});
```

Comment: Very interesting. Thank you. I have not learned about closures before. Have now reviewed the feature and it is exactly what I need to solve my problem.

Comment: Follow-up question: how would I send controls to the object within the closure? For example, I would like to send the ft0.abort from a button. However, since I have started more than one download, how would I reference the ft0.abort to the appropriate download which was started within the closure?

Comment: i've edited the answer to accommodate your follow-up question.